# Laravel validate form on type, but not required

Tags: laravel

I have an input file to upload an image. This input is optional.
But, i just want to validate if there is an image on this input.

So i did :

```
public function update(Note $note, Request $request){
 $request->validate(['image_path_01' => 'image']);
}
```

My form

```
 <form method="POST" action="{{ route('web_note_update',['note' => $note]) }}" role="form">
 @csrf
 @method('PUT')
 <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="image_path_01" name="image_path_01">
 <button type="submit">Edit</button>
 </form>
```

When i validate my form without filling up the input file, i have an error : "The field image path 01 need to be an image."

I don't understand why, because i didn't put "required" for image in my validate function.

How can i do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply because `null` is not an image. If you don't want to use required, but still want to validate the `image_path_01` is an image, you can use `nullable`:

```php
$request->validate(['image_path_01' => 'nullable|image']);
```

Also, make sure your form has `enctype="multipart/form-data` when uploading files:

```php
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('web_note_update',['note' => $note]) }}" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```